# Integers with $k$ prime factors, in terms of the Möbius function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, probabilistic-number-theory, mobius-inversion

> A $k$-free integer is an integer $n$ such that there is no $k$th power dividing $n$. It is well known (see Murty's Problems in Analytic Number Theory q1.18 for instance) that \begin{equation}\sum_{d^k|n}\mu(d)=1_{k\textrm{-free}}(n).\end{equation} My question is - is there an analogue of this for integers $n$ with $\Omega(n)=k$, where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ counted with multiplicity?

I cannot seem to find a reference for such a formula. It seems natural to ask whether there is such a result. We know that the number of such integers up to, say $x$, is asymptotically \begin{equation}\frac{x(\log\log x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\log x};\end{equation} being as well-known as it is I would hope there is a formula like the one at the start relating to this?

Comment: Do you know such a formula for $k=1$, the set of primes? Do you have any reason to believe one exists? It doesn't seem too likely to me

Comment: One does have that the von Mangoldt function equals $-\sum_{d | n}\mu(d)\log d$, and if you take powers of $\log$, the resulting convolution is related to products of more primes.